# NoSuchEJBException when running maven test

Tags: java, maven, jboss, ejb, jndi

I have a maven client project that i run as maven test. First thing i do in the junit test is a lookup using the jndi string. Here i receive a stateless bean proxy which is cast to a remote interface. As soon as i call a method from the interface (like saving some domain objects wich uses a data access object wich uses jpa) i receive the exception

```
javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: No such EJB[appname=,modulename=someName,distinctname=,beanname=SomeBean]
```

The documentation says: "A NoSuchEJBException is thrown if an attempt is made to invoke a business method on a stateful session or singleton object that no longer exists". The thing is that the bean is stateless and not stateful or a singleton. I'm also quite sure that the jndi string is correct, because if i make the same lookup and persistence-method-call in the main method of the client project (run as maven build with "install jboss-as:deploy") everything works fine.
Any suggestions how i could use the persistence methods from the proxy when testing? Some colleagues have a similar setup and it works for them without Arquillian or so.

Comment: Your colleagues uses stateless sessionbeans via remote interface?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but it works now. What I did was removing the getter-method for the EntityManager within the abstract generic DaoBean that all DaoBeans inherit. Having the getter was suddenly shown as an Error while executing the client (it wasn't shown as error before).